# Github desktop sync spins indefinitely

Tags: github, github-desktop

The syncing starts and says "Syncing" with the spinning loading wheel. 
It just goes on forever but never updates.

This is happening across all my repos, on every branch. 
It started after the update before last.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the application. This only occurs on one workstation, my other workstation has the same version and syncs fine. 
Any ideas for fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel pretty dumb about this, but running `git sync` in the terminal fixed the GUI.

Comment: I am still having this issue even after issuing this command in power shell

Answer (score 1):

I am having this issue in a single repository (the others work) and `git sync` did not fix the issue.

I removed the repository including deleting the repository folder and re-cloned it. This did not solve the issue either.

Comment: Sometimes I have to delete the portable git folder in app data, and let the gui re extract it. This does not akways work either.