# GitHub desktop stuck on syncing?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I'm trying out GitHub desktop for windows. I downloaded it from https://desktop.github.com/. Logged in with my GitHub credentials and created a git repository locally with the +, create and added the path to the project on my local machine that I wanted to initiate as a git repository. I added the node_modules to the .gitignore file and had 16 files left which I wrote a "summary" message for and pressed the "commit to master" button. It now says "no changes" so I pressed "publish" which I read should give me the option to create a public or private repository. But instead I just see "syncing" which never stops nor upload anything to my GitHub account.

I then had to close the desktop app to make it stop. Next I tried to create an empty repository on GitHub and add the ssh then the https address to repository settings/remote (according to [Github Desktop: Not able to publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578258/github-desktop-not-able-to-publish)) but the same thing happened again.

I have also tried 'git sync' with git shell (according to [Github desktop sync spins indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005958/github-desktop-sync-spins-indefinitely)), which works in the shell but it does not fix the GitHub Desktop app; next time I tried pressing the sync button it just keeps spinning.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: This looks like a bug report that should be addressed to GitHub's support.

Comment: I believe I have same issue. + Seems like I can clone repo, but clicking at commit dots doesn't reveal information.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?I have been trying this using PluralSight Tutorial but looks like the syncing just never stops.. is this tool even worth using? or have you started using some other tool tortoise git like

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem, then I tried running `git push` from the shell and it worked.

Comment: This works, but here is the funny thing. I tried using Fork instead of GitHub Desktop and it was still not working there either. Only the git-cli worked as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a separate issue entirely, but I had been using GitHub Desktop for a while with a particular repository, and today it started getting stuck on Fetch. I discovered that it was an authentication issue, even though I did not get any indication that that was the case. Still, I solved the problem by restarting the ssh agent. I ran `start-ssh-agent` in CMD (on Windows), closed Github Desktop, and re-opened it, and the problem went away. Again, this may be completely unrelated to OP's issue, but perhaps this will help others like myself who may have stumbled on this question.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution seems to be to go to GitHub.com then:

```
1. delete your old repository.
2. create a new repository of the same name, make sure to add the readme file.  
3. clone the repository back to your computer, but give it either a new local name or a new location.  
4. copy and paste the files from your old local repository to the new one.  
5. commit and sync the files.
```

It is a hassle, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem.  I would just add to the answers here that command line git still worked.  I'm a command line newbie doing it, but if you navigate to the directory within your workspace, and just 
    git push
that seemed to work.
Where it was a new branch, the git error message gave you the additional needed options.
That at least saves you from having to copy/paste work since your last sync.